# iPtables is not allowing ports to open

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, ubuntu-16.04

I am having a problem with my iptables. I have a server setup that is a web server, openvpn, file server, NAS. I have the default INPUT to drop connections, but allow certain ports to be opened. My iptables is as following:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
82  5418 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    92 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       ***.*.**.**          0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  enp0s7 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:21
0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp0s7 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:2934
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp0s7 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp0s7 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:81
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp0s7 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:83
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp0s7 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:85
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp0s7 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  enp0s7 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:1195

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   enp0s7  10.8.0.0/24          192.168.1.0/24       ctstate NEW
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   enp0s7  10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      enp0s7  192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 84 packets, 51706 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain BLACKLIST (0 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain LOGDROP (0 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain SPAM (0 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain TRU (0 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain WEB (0 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I was going to have default as ACCEPT and have a final DROP statement under the LOGDROP chain but it still does the same thing. Right now I still have it behind my routers firewall (yes I still have those ports open on that firewall), but once I get iptables set up correctly I will place my server in DMZ mode.

When I place the INPUT default to ACCEPT and I test the port via Shields up it will state that those ports are open. But as soon as I change the default to DROP (or placing a drop statement under the LOGDROP chain), shields up says the port is closed.

I have also tried specifying from any connection or specifically stating my network card (enp0s7)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please replace the iptables output (which is appropriately formatted, which is good) with the output of `iptables -Lnv`. There's a handful of rules in there where I get the distinct feeling that what you are showing is sufficiently incomplete to not be meaningful.

Comment: I have updated the output. (command iptables -Lnv did not work but iptables -vnL did)

Comment: You'd rather give the output in yet-an-other-format: `iptables-save -c` dumps the rules more like when you wrote them. It appears easier to understand them (at least for me). The `-c` part is to include the counters. Be sure to run it after failing attempts. It looks strange that none of your DROP rules have a counter set.